# Tensorflow 2.3: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I wanted to load the text file borrowed from [here](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/), where each line represent a json string like following:

```
{"overall": 2.0, "verified": true, "reviewTime": "02 4, 2014", "reviewerID": "A1M117A53LEI8", "asin": "7508492919", "reviewerName": "Sharon Williams", "reviewText": "DON'T CARE FOR IT.  GAVE IT AS A GIFT AND THEY WERE OKAY WITH IT.  JUST NOT WHAT I EXPECTED.", "summary": "CASE", "unixReviewTime": 1391472000}
```

I would like to extract only `reviewText` and `overall` feature from the dataset using tensorflow but facing following error.

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-4-419019a35c5e>:9 None  *
        line_dataset = line_dataset.map(lambda row: transform(row))
    <ipython-input-4-419019a35c5e>:2 transform  *
        str_example = example.numpy().decode("utf-8")

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

My code snippet looks like following:

```
def transform(example):
    str_example = example.numpy().decode("utf-8")
    json_example = json.loads(str_example)
    overall = json_example.get('overall', None)
    text = json_example.get('reviewText', None)
    return (overall, text)

line_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames = [file_path])
line_dataset = line_dataset.map(lambda row: transform(row))
for example in line_dataset.take(5):
    print(example)
```

I am using tensorflow 2.3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input pipeline of a dataset is always traced into a graph (as if you used [`@tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function)) to make it faster, which means, among other things, that you cannot use `.numpy()`. You can however use [`tf.numpy_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) to access the data as a NumPy array within the graph:

```py
def transform(example):
    # example will now by a NumPy array
    str_example = example.decode("utf-8")
    json_example = json.loads(str_example)
    overall = json_example.get('overall', None)
    text = json_example.get('reviewText', None)
    return (overall, text)

line_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames = [file_path])
line_dataset = line_dataset.map(
    lambda row: tf.numpy_function(transform, row, (tf.float32, tf.string)))
for example in line_dataset.take(5):
    print(example)
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit wordy, but try it like this:

```
def transform(example):     
    str_example = example.numpy().decode("utf-8")     
    json_example = json.loads(str_example)     
    overall = json_example.get('overall', None)     
    text = json_example.get('reviewText', None)     
    return (overall, text)  

line_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames = [file_path]) 
line_dataset = line_dataset.map(
    lambda input:     
        tf.py_function(transform, [input], (tf.float32, tf.string))
)  
for example in line_dataset.take(5):     
    print(example)
```

This particular snippet works for any python function, not only the for numpy functions. So, if you need functions like `print`, `input` and so on, you can use this. You don't have to know all the details, but if you are interested, please ask me. :)

Comment: What is the purpose of decorator used in `tf_function`?

Comment: I modified your snippet to cut it short and my version of your snippet works as well.

```def transform(example):
    str_example = example.numpy().decode("utf-8")
    json_example = json.loads(str_example)
    overall = json_example.get('overall', None)
    text = json_example.get('reviewText', None)
    return (overall, text)

line_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames = [file_path])
line_dataset = line_dataset.map(lambda input: tf.py_function(transform, [input], (tf.float32, tf.string)))

for example in line_dataset.take(5):
    print(example)
```

Comment: With your permission, I'll update my answer with your snippet. Your code looks better :)