# Printing Tensor elements (v1.14)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to understand how keras/tensorflow work.

In this example I'm working with, an `LSTM` network with a defined `loss` function.
I want to print the values in `y_pred` and `loss` variables in this example, however a standard `print()` function will not print the actual numeric values.

When I try `print()` function, I get the following output: `Tensor("loss_13/dense_14_loss/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 10, dropout=0.10, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 4, activation='softmax'))
regressor.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = weight_fx(np.array([0.005,0.20,0.79,0.005])), metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'])

def weight_fx(weights):
    weights = K.variable(weights)     
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred /= K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        print(y_pred)
        loss = y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weights
        return loss
    
    return loss
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
import numpy as np

X = tf.ones((10,10,10))
y = tf.ones((10,1))
def weight_fx(weights):
    weights = K.variable(weights)     
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred /= K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        tf.print(y_pred)
        loss = y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weights
        return loss
    
    return loss

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 10, dropout=0.10, return_sequences = True, 
                   input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 4, activation='softmax'))
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = weight_fx(np.array([0.005,0.20,0.79,0.005])), metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'])
regressor.fit(X,y)
```

- Q: Why do you see `Tensor("loss_13/dense_14_loss/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`?
- A: Tensorflow expects that the loss function is going to get called very often, so it is paramount to optimize it as much as possible. Tensorflow has a way of doing this, called 'tracing'. This basically means passing in a 'detector' variable that 'experiences' all operations in the function and remembers them. Then, based on these experiences, Tensorflow builds a separate so-called 'graph' function that is way faster and lacks ability to call many common functions with side-effect in python. Like `print()`. What you see there is a detector or a 'tracer'. It only runs once.
- Then how do I debug?
- Several ways for doing this. If you want to `print`-debug, use `tf.print`. In my experience this sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. In case when it doesn't, and you still see the detector variable only, use the `model.run_eagerly = True` or pass it as an argument in `model.compile`. Even if you do not use `tf.print` and set `run_eagerly`, python's built-in `print` will still work (Try this).
  Last but not least, you can wrap all your side-effect functions in a `tf.py_function`. This requires a bit more code and a sample copy-and-paste code can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63558666/14142345).

Also, Make sure to first define the function and then use it in the `model.compile`, especially if you are using Jupyter notebook. A buggy old declaration might still persist in memory and will probably ruin your day.

Did this help?

Comment: Thanks, added `run_eagerly` after the `regressor = Sequential()` line and after `regressor.compile` but I still get the same `Tensor("loss...` output, any idea why this could be? I had to execute `tf.executing_eagerly()` also.

Comment: I updated answer. I ran  the code and now it prints everything fine for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: Hi torniko, I think I liked the previous answer version (lots of explanation, almost no code) better than this code-only one. Please consider providing a code proposal along with an enlightening explanation. Only giving code gives the impression that you, like many askers, mistake StackOverflow for a free code-writing service.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry, I was in a hurry to run update the answer. Now I'll add the proper explanation.

Comment: @Yunnosch Please review the addition above and tell me if it is up to standards of SO. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, just ran your code above and I did not see any printed output. Moreover, I had to specify a `steps_per_epoch` parameter as well. Could this be a versioning issue?

Comment: It might just be the case. My tf version is 2.3.0.

Comment: If you can upgrade, I'll consider my answer complete, otherwise, I'll try your version '2.1.0' to reproduce above behaviour.

Comment: Apologies, I have version 1.14 , will try to upgrade now and let you know.

Comment: Consider upgrading in a separate environment if you use anaconda or venv. There is a slight chance that it might break your old code.

Comment: Thank you, once I upgraded to `2.3` I am able to see the output. However, I did have to add the `run_eager` line as you recommended above.

Comment: Seems an upvotable answer now. ;-)

Comment: @tornikeo any idea what the pitfalls are when I implement the above in a more 'objected oriented' manner? I.e. I've created a `class` and its almost identical to the approach above (the custom loss is defined in class), however I get blank when I print `y_pred` or `y_true`. Figure I ask a general question before posting an entirely new question.

Comment: @Josh As a rule of thumb, always start designing the model with the `run_eagerly` attribute set to true. Only remove it when you need more speed. This will save you a lot of time and debugging pains. Try it now, the y_pred and y_true should be printed just fine.

Comment: I don't think thats the issue here, I've been able to debug just fine prior to making my approach more object-oriented-friendly. The issue may be in wrapping `keras` within my `class` object. I may have to post new question.

Comment: @tornikeo, I've posted a new question here, would appreciate greatly if you could take a look - didi madloba!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this yet but you should always use:

```
tf.print(value)
```

Instead of just normal

```
print(value)
```

Tensorflow has implemented this function specifically for this. Hopefully, this helps!

Comment: thanks, still getting what looks like the data structure of the variables: `name: "loss_15/dense_16_loss/PrintV2"
op: "PrintV2" input: "loss_15/dense_16_loss/StringFormat" attr {key: "end"
  value { s: "\r\n" } } attr {  key: "output_stream"  value {    s: "stderr"  } }`

Comment: Do you want to fit the function?