# Tensorflow 2.3: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' with eager mode enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have seen other similar questions here but they didn't help me.
I'm using tensorflow 2.3 and I'm having an issue when i try to call a function that returns a keras.Model  .

```
 AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' Tensorflow 2.3
```

I write here a snippet of my model

```
    inputs = Input(shape=(n_ch, height, width), batch_size=batchSize)

    conv_1 = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same',data_format='channels_first')(inputs)
    conv_1 = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(conv_1)
    conv_1 = Activation("relu")(conv_1)
    conv_2 = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same',data_format='channels_first')(conv_1)

    conv_2 = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(conv_2)
    conv_2 = Activation("relu")(conv_2)


    pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(conv_2)


    unpool_1 = Lambda(unpool)(pool_1)

    conv_25 = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same',data_format='channels_first')(unpool_1)
    conv_25 = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(conv_25)
    conv_25 = Activation("relu")(conv_25)
    conv_26 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1),data_format="channels_first",activation="sigmoid")(conv_25)
    print("Build decoder done..")

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv_26, name="SegNet")

    return model
```

I get an error here:

```
def unpool(pool):
    updates = pool.numpy()
    [...]
```

It says that pool is a Tensor object but I don't understand why.
I want to use eager mode and `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns True.
I also tried to set run_eagerly=True and/or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` but nothing.

Any suggestions? I don't know what to do. Thank you

Comment: How are the two code snippets related to each other? What do you call ``unpool`` with? Please provide a complete code example that produces the error.

Comment: Btw eager execution is active by default in tensorflow 2.x, the stated commands are not necessary.

Comment: @Alperino unpool is used with Lambda layers,  look at the code
I know that eager execution is active by default but I tried that anyway

Comment: I believe a `tf.keras` model ends up being decorated with `tf.function`, so each command within the model is not executing eagerly anymore. Try with `experimental_run_tf_function=False` in your call to `model.compile`.

Comment: I guess you are trying to insert some ``numpy``-operations as calculation steps into a ``tf.model``, which is not possible the way you implied. Please be more specific on what you are trying to achieve and what ``unpool`` is meant to do.

Comment: Here is the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557955/tensorflow-2-3-attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-numpy) resolved. Please let us know if this solves the issue.